# error when creating a file on Python: Access denied

Tags: python, model, jupyter, spyder, calibration

I know this is a very repeated error, however, I've tried what I've found on the web and the error persists:

```
[Errno 13] Access denied: C:/Users/Data.../
```

[image]

How can I fix this? What I am trying to do is a groundwater model calibration using Python (with PyEMU & PEST++) and I'm creating a control file so I can continue to the real deal of the whole thing...I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

I'm new to coding but... do I have to run this from root or something similar? How can I do that?

Please any suggestion is very appreciated I'm very very frustated...thank you.

Comment: The user who you've logged in as does not have persmission to create a file or whatever you're trying to do in the folder where you're trying to do that.

Comment: I'm running Conda/Jupyter as admin. I'm guessing that's not enough? :((

Comment: Check the permission for the folder where you're trying to create the file.

Comment: I do have full permission, I did check that :(

Comment: Strange. Can you post the full error message & traceback?

Comment: Just edited my post with it!

Comment: Does the filename you're writing to end with `...`? Maybe that's the issue. Also the destination seems to be on  different drive `E:\\`. Make sure you have permissions in that drive.

Comment: Oh no I just hid the whole folder direction :). And yes I do have permission there, I recently changed it and ran Python again, just to see if it'd work if I changed the dir. But it didn't :( I've been trying a bit of everything!

Comment: The `...` seems to be there in the screenshot as well though

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by including a file name (for the control file) in the function call:

```
pst = pf.build_pst('pest.pst')
```

See the docs:
https://pyemu.readthedocs.io/en/develop/autoapi/pyemu/utils/pst_from/